# How can I remove myself as an admin of a group?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

There is a group that I was a member of. Suddenly one day, all of a sudden I became admin of a group.

How can I remove myself as an admin of the group? And how can I make someone else an admin of that group?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Long press the group chat and hit "Delete and exit group" - your chat will be deleted and you will be out of the group. Someone else will be auto-selected as the group-admin in your place.

Comment: is it auto selected or there is some logic behind it?

Comment: There has to be some logic behind the auto-selection, but I'm still trying to figure out what it could be.

Comment: I would still like to keep the chat, it's just that since I was auto-selected in the first place and don't want to be admin any more. Thanks for the answer but still looking for solution. Anyone any more thoughts on this?

Comment: Here's the official WhatsApp documentation - http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/general/21073373. As suspected, the leader is selected "randomly".

Answer (score 0):

Talk to a person that willing to be an admin in the group. After you selected the person, remove everybody in the group except you and the selected (next going to be admin). Make sure just left two of you in the group, then remove yourself from the group. The last person will automatically will be the admin.

Last but not least, the new admin have to select all the joiners or members of the group that been removed by you (ex-admin) back to the group. So make sure he/she have all the numbers of the group before you make the move.

Comment: Sorry, Not a practical solution if you have 50 users in the group. But thanks for the answer. +1 for that.